# nodejs - request - express- use file readStream inside of a post handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, nodejs-stream

I'm using nodejs and express4. I have a form - post method (file upload as base64) and I'm saving this file to a gridfs with streams.

this is my code:

```
exports.transcribe = function (gridfs, req, res) {

    const buffer = Buffer.from(req.body.file.split(';base64,')[1], 'base64')
    let contentType = req.body.file.split(';base64,')[0].replace('data:', '')
    streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(gridfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: uuid.v4() + '.txt',
        content_type: contentType,
        metadata: {
            user: req.user
        }
    }))
    // this is request-promise-native
    request.post({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        uri: process.env.REST_ENDPOINT,
        // stream is created with streamifier from a buffer object
        formData: {'file': streamifier.createReadStream(buffer)}
    }).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
    res.status(200).json({file: file, user: req.user})
}
```

the code works when execuded synchronous but it does not inside the request handling.

I read about that maybe the stream is canceled before I am able to send it. 
What is missing is the content of the file. The request itself is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I was able to work around the problem. I'm not using the streams anymore:

```
exports.transcribe = function (gridfs, req, res) {

    const buffer = Buffer.from(req.body.file.split(';base64,')[1], 'base64')
    let contentType = req.body.file.split(';base64,')[0].replace('data:', '')
    streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(gridfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: uuid.v4() + '.txt',
        content_type: contentType,
        metadata: {
            user: req.user
        }
    }))
    request.post(process.env.REST_ENDPOINT, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        formData: {
            'file': {
                value: buffer,
                options: {
                    filename: 'transcribeme.txt',
                    contentType: contentType
                }
            }
        }
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        res.status(200).json({user: req.user})
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
        res.status(500).json({user: req.user})
    })

}
```